# Location of css file in a GWT project

Tags: css, gwt

I have css file named Sample.css which contain the below contents.

```
         .bandit-report{
       margin-left: 20px;
          }
         .bandit-report1{
         margin-left: 50px;
          }
```

I have the ABCD.gwt.xml where I have made the below entry for the css file

```
    <stylesheet src='Sample.css' />
```

I set the style name using setStyleName(String) method. However the margin-left changes are not getting reflected. I dont know where to place the Sample.css file. I have currently place both ABCD.gwt.xml and Sample.css in the same directory.

Kindly Help.

Comment: I changed the entry made in ABCD.gwt.xml to as below. Now its working in dev mode

     <stylesheet src='/Sample.css' />

Answer (score 4):

Relative paths in `<stylesheet>` in a gwt.xml files are relative to the "module base URL" (returned by `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` on the client-side code; this is the folder into which GWT will generate the nocache.js file and everything else). Having a file output in this directory is as easy as putting it in your *public path*, which by default is a `public` subfolder of your GWT module (next to your `client` subpackage). It's worth noting that *public paths* are inherited from modules you `<inherit>`; this is how GWT's built-in themes work.

If you put your stylesheet in your `war` folder, then you shouldn't *inject* it from your gwt.xml, you should rather load it with a `<link rel=stylesheet>` in your HTML host page.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the entry made in ABCD.gwt.xml to as below. Now its working.

```
     <stylesheet src='/Sample.css' />
```

Comment: Don't answer your post. Edit it with new content.

Comment: @Krish: that'll work in DevMode because your app is deployed at the root of the server, but it's likely to break depending on how you deploy your app later. See my answer for what you should do.

Comment: I tried this myself a while ago and it causes issues outside of devmode, so not that good a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser developer panel to find out the location of css file.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder named `public` in the same place where your `client`, `server` and `shared` folders are and put it in there, that's the default location it will look.